Traceless Hermitian matrices with simultaneously vanishing Rayleigh quotients
Let $D$ be an integer greater than 1. What is the largest number $N$, such that for all sets of $N$ Hermitian $D\times D$ traceless matrices $M_i$, $i=1,\dots,N$, there exists a non-zero complex vector $v$, such that $v^HM_iv = 0$ for all $i$? ($v^H = (v^*)^T$ is the conjugate transpose).
Example.
For $D=2$, $N$ must be less than 3, because for a set $M_i = \sigma_i$, $i=1,2,3$, where $\sigma_i$ are the Pauli matrices, for any vector $v$:
$$
\sum_i (v^H M_i v)^2 = \Vert v\Vert^4 \neq 0\,,
$$
so $v^H M_i v$ cannot all simultaneously vanish. However, for $N=2$ it is possible: let $v_1,v_2$ be eigenvectors of $M_1$ with eigenvalues $\lambda,-\lambda$. Then for $v = v_1 + \alpha v_2$, with $|\alpha| = 1$, $v^H M_1 v = 0$. Then
$$
v^H M_2 v = 
\alpha (v_1^H M_2 v_2) + \alpha^{-1} (v_2^H M_2 v_1).
$$
Then any solution to $\alpha^2 = -(v_2^H M_2 v_1)/(v_1^H M_2 v_2)$ will satisfy $v^H M_2 v = 0$. Thus $N=2$ is the answer.
Conjecture (false). For any $D$, $N$ is upper-bounded by $D^2-2$, because $D^2-1$ is the dimension of space of traceless Hermitian matrices, which for any $v$ contains $P_v - 1_{D\times D}/D$, where $P_v$ is the projector onto $\operatorname{span}\{v\}$, the Rayleigh quotient of which is $1-1/D\neq 0$. My conjecture is that $N = D^2-2$ is the correct answer.
Motivation. In quantum mechanics Rayleigh quotients $(v^HMv) / (v^H v)$ describe expectation values of quantum observables. The question then can be read: for a quantum system in $D$-dimensional Hilbert space, what is the maximum number of independent observables, that can have simultaneously vanishing expectation value.

New conjecture. As proven in @Nathaniel Johnston's answer and comments thereafter, the answer is bounded by $N < 2D - 1$. The current conjecture (checked numerically with random matrices) is $N = 2D-2$.

The correct value of $N$ is
$$
N = \begin{cases}
2 & \text{if $D = 2$},\\ 3 & \text{if $D \geq 3$}.
\end{cases}
$$
The original question already proved that $N = 2$ when $D = 2$, and Michał's answer here shows that $N \leq 3$ when $D \geq 3$. So all that's left to prove is that $N \geq 3$ when $D \geq 3$.
To this end, for $3$ Hermitian traceless matrices $M_1$, $M_2$, $M_3$, consider the set
$$
W = \{(v^HM_1v, v^HM_2v, v^HM_3v) : \|v\| = 1\}.
$$
This is called the ``joint numerical range'' of $M_1$, $M_2$, and $M_3$, and it is known to be convex [1] (this depends crucially on both facts that these matrices are at least $3 \times 3$ and that there are 3 of them). In particular, this implies that
$$
\left(\int_v v^HM_1v \, dv, \int_v v^HM_2v \, dv, \int_v v^HM_3v \, dv\right) \in W,
$$
where the integration is performed over all unit vectors $v$, with respect to uniform spherical measure. Since $M_i$ is traceless for each $i$, we have $\int_v v^HM_iv \, dv = 0$ for each $i$, so $(0,0,0) \in W$. In other words, there exists $v$ with $\|v\| = 1$ such that $v^HM_iv = 0$ for all $i$, and we're done.
[1] Au-Yeung, Yik-Hoi; Poon, Yiu-Tung, A remark on the convexity and positive definiteness concerning Hermitian matrices, Southeast Asian Bull. Math. 3, 85-92 (1979). ZBL0432.15012

I'll prove some bounds that disprove the conjectured $N = D^2 - 2$ when $D \geq 3$.

Bound 1: $N \leq D(D-1)$.
I'll illustrate this bound when $D = 3$ (so $N \leq 6$). Consider the following 7 of the 8 Gell-Mann matrices:
$$
M_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, M_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i & 0 \\ i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, M_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -i \\ 0 & i & 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
$$
M_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, M_5 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -i \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ i & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, M_6 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
$$
M_7 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
It's not too difficult to show that if $v$ has $v^HM_iv = 0$ for $1 \leq i \leq 6$ then $v$ has at most $1$ non-zero entry. But if it has just one non-zero entry then it can't be the case that $v^HM_7v = 0$. So there is no non-zero $v$ for which $v^HM_iv = 0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq 7$.
To generalize this to higher $D$, replace $M_1, \ldots, M_6$ by the $D(D-1)$ matrices $E_{j,k} + E_{k,j}$ and $iE_{j,k} - iE_{k,j}$ for $1 \leq j < k \leq D$, where $E_{j,k}$ is the matrix with $1$ in the $(j,k)$-entry and $0$ elsewhere, and replace $M_7$ by any traceless diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries non-zero.

The next bound is strictly better than Bound 1 above, but we have to work a bit harder to prove it.
Bound 2: When $D \geq 3$, we have $N \leq D(D-1)/2 + D - 2$.
Again, I'll illustrate this bound first when $D = 3$. This time, take the following 5 matrices:
$$
M_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, M_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, M_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
M_4 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, M_5 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
If $v$ has $v^HM_iv = 0$ for $1 \leq i \leq 3$, then the off-diagonal entries of $vv^H$ are all purely imaginary (i.e., of the form $bi$, where $b$ is a real number (maybe equal to $0$)). However, $vv^H$ is also a positive semidefinite rank-1 matrix, and the only positive semidefinite rank-1 matrices whose off-diagonal entries are purely imaginary are equal to zero outside of a single $2 \times 2$ principal submatrix (proof: $vv^H + (vv^H)^*$ is diagonal with rank at most $2$, so it has at most $2$ non-zero diagonal entries, so $vv^H$ also hat at most $2$ non-zero diagonal entries).
But then $v^HM_iv = 0$ for $4 \leq i \leq 5$ forces the diagonal entries of $vv^H$ to all equal each other, which (when $D \geq 3$) can only happen if $v$ is the zero vector.
Generalizing this to higher $D$ makes use of the $D(D-1)/2$ matrices of the form $E_{j,k} + E_{k,j}$ for $1 \leq j < k \leq D$ and the $D-1$ matrices of the form $E_{j,j} - E_{j+1,j+1}$ for $1 \leq j < D$.

Amazing progress! Can't you actually improve your bounds further by following approach of Bound 1, but only taking $M_1,M_2,M_4,M_5$, and $2E_{11} - E_{22} - E_{33}$? More generally: $E_{1j}+E_{j1}$, $−iE_{1j}+iE_{j1}$ for $j=2,…,N$, and $(D-1)E_{11} - \sum_{j=2}^N E_{jj}$. This would improve the bound to $N<2D−1$. I also did some numerical checks with random matrices, and for $N=2D−2$ I could always make the Rayleigh quotients vanish.

@MichałJan - Oh very nice! Yes, that seems to work, and it seems very believable that bound would be tight. If it’s true that every sub space of Hermitian matrices with dimension strictly larger than $(n-1)^2$ contains a rank 1 matrix then your bound is tight. I’d expect that’s a known result, but I haven’t found a reference yet.

Sorry, my “$n$” in my previous comment should be “$D$”.

The new conjecture is false for $D=4$ and $N=2D-2=6$.
Consider the Pauli matrices
$$\sigma_1=\left[\begin{matrix} & 1 \\ 1 & \end{matrix}\right],\
\sigma_2=\left[\begin{matrix} & -i \\ i & \end{matrix}\right],\
\sigma_3=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & \\ & -1 \end{matrix}\right]$$
and the following sextuple of $4\times4$ trace-zero hermitian matrices:
$$\left[\begin{matrix} \sigma_1 & \\ & 0 \end{matrix}\right],\
\left[\begin{matrix} \sigma_2 & \\ & 0 \end{matrix}\right],\
\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & \\ & \sigma_1 \end{matrix}\right],\
\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & \\ & \sigma_2 \end{matrix}\right],\
\left[\begin{matrix} \sigma_3 & \\ & \sigma_3 \end{matrix}\right],\
\left[\begin{matrix} \sigma_3 & \\ & -\sigma_3 \end{matrix}\right].$$
Suppose that $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_4)^T$ satisfies
$\mathbf{x}^H A\mathbf{x}=0$ for each $A$ in the above.
The first two implies $x_1\overline{x_2}=0$.
The middle two implies $x_3\overline{x_4}=0$.
And the last two implies $|x_1|^2+|x_3|^2=|x_2|^2+|x_4|^2$
and $|x_1|^2+|x_4|^2=|x_2|^2+|x_3|^2$, or equivalently $|x_1|=|x_2|$ and $|x_3|=|x_4|$.
These altogether imply $\mathbf{x}=0$.
ADDED:
Let's consider the smallest $N=N(D)$ that such that violates the conjecture for $D$.
We claim $N$ has at most logarithmic growth in $D$.
There are $D\times D$ matrices $A_1,\ldots,A_{N(D)}$
with the following property:
if $y\in\mathbb{C}^D$ satisfies $y^HA_iy=0$ for all $i$, then $y=0$. Then, the diagonal sums
$1_D\oplus-1_D, A_1\oplus0_D,\ldots,A_{N(D)}\oplus0_D$
witness $N(2D) \le 1+N(D)$.

Thank you @NarutakaOZAWA! So for even $D$, the upper bound can be now set at $N < 3D/2$ by just taking $M_i$ to each have one of the Pauli matrices in one of the consecutive non-overlapping 2x2 blocks.

In fact, N grows at most logarithmically. I'm not sure if it's unbounded(!).

I believe this proves that $N<4$ for all $D>2$.

Take 4 matrices with dimension $D>2$:
\begin{gather}
M_\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_\alpha \\
& 0_{D-2}
\end{pmatrix}\,,\qquad \alpha=1,2,3\,,\\
M_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
D-1 \\
& -I_{D-1}
\end{pmatrix}    
\end{gather}
where $I_n$ and $0_D$ are $n\times n$ identity and zero matrices respectively. $v$ satisfies $v^H M_i v = 0$ for $i=1,\dots 3$ iff $v_1 = v_2 = 0$. But this implies $v^H M_4 v = -\lVert v \rVert^2 \neq 0$.
