Does every $(n-1)^2 + 1$-dimensional subspace of $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices that contains identity, contain a rank-1 matrix?
Let $M_i$, $i=1,\dots,(n-1)^2+1$, $M_1 = 1_{n\times n}$ be a set of linearly-independent Hermitian $n\times n$ matrices. Show that there exists a rank-1 matrix $P$, which is a linear combination of $M_i$s:
$$
P = \sum_{i=1}^{(n-1)^2+1} a_i M_i
$$
Motivaion: The positive answer to this question will resolve an earlier stated problem Traceless Hermitian matrices with simultaneously vanishing Rayleigh quotients.

For what it's worth, the answer is known to be "yes" if you remove the "Hermitian" requirement (i.e., any $((n-1)^2+1)$-dimensional subspace of $n \times n$ complex matrices contains a rank-1 matrix). Unfortunately, that doesn't solve this problem since it relies crucially on the fact that it's a complex vector space (whereas the $n \times n$ Hermitian matrices is a real vector space, which makes things trickier). I don't know of a way around this obstacle yet.

Thanks! Could you provide me a reference to the complex case?

Sure! This is my go-to reference for this (there may be an earlier/more canonical reference that is not in quantum information theory language; not sure): arXiv:0706.0705. Theorem 11 with r=2 is the result I described.

I think the answer is NO, if $a_i$'s are required real.

@NarutakaOZAWA - The $a_i$'s being required real is the only interesting case, so I'd love to see an argument in that case (as I noted above, if the $a_i$'s are allowed to be complex then the answer is known to be "yes").

@Nathaniel Johnston: I wrote it at  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/474920/traceless-hermitian-matrices-with-simultaneously-vanishing-rayleigh-quotients.

Thank you @NarutakaOZAWA, this answers my question here, counterexample being $P = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{1,1} & 0 & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} \
0 & a_{1,1} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} \
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & 0 \
a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & 0 & a_{3,3} \
\end{array}
\right)$. $\operatorname{rank}P = 1$ does not have solutions in Hermitian matrices.
